# Will staying longer than planned in Japan cause problems?

Tags: japan, canadian-citizens

I have a question regarding my visa. I have a Canadian passport and I booked a ticket to Japan for 30 days. I know that my passport allows me to stay in Japan for 90 days. I'm thinking, for example, If extend my stay for about 83 days in Japan, will this pose a problem with the immigration, will it affect my travel in the future to other countries?

I'm anxious it would be an overstay. I don't really know how visas work and this my first time travelling outside the country.

Edit: I recently got back from Japan. I stayed 2 months and I wanted to come back after 7 months to meet my gf again. My original plan is to stay 30 days. BTW, it is not my first time. This will be my second time visiting but I don't really know how visa works.

Comment: Do you have a visa or is it a visa free stay in Japan? And have you already entered Japan?

Comment: If you haven't arrived yet, say you want to stay for 84 days. Then if you leave early (with your original tickets) there's no problem. If you have already arrived please edit your question to indicate this.

Comment: Note that Japan can be quite expensive. Also if this is your first stay in Japan, you are self-organising your trip (no guide or local friends) and you don’t speak Japanese, be prepared for a cultural shock and a big language barrier. It gets better with time, though. But no issues at all staying longer than initially planned on a visa-free entry, definitely won’t be an overstay (as long as you leave before the 90 days of course!).

Comment: @jcaron Japan CAN be expensive but in general it's not, especially given the weak yen currently. I don't speak any Japanese and didn't find that to be a barrier. Major cities all have English signs. Not much cultural shock either unless exceedingly politeness throws you off.

Comment: @jcaron: it depends on your lifestyle. Food in convenience stores is cheap and better than the same food in other countries, and ramen restaurants are quite cheap too. There are cheap guesthouses all over Japan

Comment: @jcaron as an aside, you wrote "***Note that Japan can be quite expensive***"  My only response to that can be ... ???????!?!?!!???????    I'm surprised and confused by your comment?

Comment: Japan is not expensive. A cheap but nice meal costs around ¥1,000 ($6.6), a quite nice dinner including drinks costs ¥3,000-¥5,000 ($20-$33, tax incl., no tip necessary). A night in a small but comfortable Tokyo hotel room costs around ¥12,000-¥15,000 ($80-$100), a nice hotel costs around ¥20,000-¥25,000 ($133-$167), and a bullet train ride from Tokyo to Osaka costs ¥14,720 ($98).

Comment: @Willeke, I have been to Japan already. I stayed 60 days because my gf extended my stay. My original plan was 30 days and then I recently came back to Canada. As of this year I've been just working but I'm going to be starting school this January 6, 2025.

Comment: @jcaron Hi, I can save probably around $14,000 cad. This is my second time coming back to Japan. I recently got back from my vacation and I'm planning to comeback for the second time this October to meet my gf. My plan is to stay 1 month but if something change, will be able to stay 83 days before I come back?

Comment: @KateGregory I recently got back from Japan. I visited Japan in January 2 of this year and came back March 3 because my girlfriend extended my stay. I definitely did not overstay and I brought $7000 cad. I want to comeback again after 7 months will this create a problem with the immigration, do you think? I'm probably bringing $14,000 cad.

Answer (score 25):

When you arrive in Japan, you will receive a "Landing Permission" (上陸許可) sticker in your passport, specifying the date of entry, the date it's valid until, and the total duration in days:

[image]
(from Wikipedia)

As long as you leave Japan before or on the "Until" date, **you're fine**.

Update: A previous two-month visit, with a 7-month gap between visits, will not be a problem: it's clear you're not working illegally in Japan.

Comment: To add to what you said - as long as the exit date is before the one on the landing permission, there's no issue. Good to know they don't track entry/exit either. @Latrell, don't sweat extending your stay, just be out of Japan before that final date.

Comment: @SarahWilson What do you mean by "don't track entry/exit"? They do, leaving Japan will terminate the landing permission.

Comment: @Servaes Hey, sorry it is not my first time btw. I recently just got back from my trip to Japan I stayed 2 months because my gf extended my stay. I want to comeback for another visit again after 7 months of being outside of Japan. I just want to experience fall season there. I just want to stay 30 days this time because I have to come back for school. I'm also bringing $14,000 cad lol. Do you think immigration will take a big deal of this?

Answer (score 9):

> My anxiousness is telling me that it's an overstay.

Some countries grant entry for a period **up to** X days on arrival based on what the traveller states at the port of entry.

Based on the text of the Japanese Ministry of Foreign Affairs, this is **not** the case for Japan.

They will grant 90 days, by default, for Canadians on arrival (landing).
(There is no mention on how often you may do this per year.)

If asked when entering, you should state that you intend to stay for around 84 days.

---

> **Period of Stay**
> The period of stay granted **at the time of the landing** permission will be ... and "90 days" for other countries and regions.

---

**Sources**:

- [Exemption of Visa (Short-Term Stay) | Ministry of Foreign Affairs of Japan](https://www.mofa.go.jp/j_info/visit/visa/short/novisa.html)

Comment: I’m note sure about saying one wants to stay for 84 days if all the arrangements (return flight, hotel bookings, etc.) are only for 30.

Comment: @jcaron A change in plans is not that unusual.

Comment: No, that's why stating the you want to stay for 30 days (the original plan) and then change it to 84 days later seems to me to be more logical than saying you want to stay 84 when you currently have everything planned for 30.

Comment: I would say I’ve planned to stay for 30 days, but might decide to extend that for longer. Be sure to have proof you meet all the [entry requirements](https://travel.gc.ca/destinations/japan#entryexit)

Comment: I would think that "I have plans for 30 days but am considering extending my stay to 80-85 days" would be as honest and accurate as possible.

Comment: @jcaron Im just anxious cuz I read some people get interrogated because they stay 30 days and leave the country for 2-3 weeks and then come back again to extend their stay in Japan so they can get another 90 days. However, this is not the case for me, Im coming back after 7 months. I'm just scared that I will have trouble with the Japanese immigration.

Answer (score 1):

I might say I find some of the answers here somewhat confusing

Facts,

#### (1) They **WILL MARK YOU** as 90 days. End of story.

If (from Canada) you were (somehow) marked as 31 days or 13 days or 40 days or some number other than 90, it would mean some wholly drastic intervention and events, you would have been interrogated for hours, they suspect you are an ADHD drugs dealer, you are a well-known international criminal, or whatever.

You will be marked as 90 days.

#### (2) I have never, ever, EVER been asked "how long I'm staying"

.. when entering Japan. And I've never heard of anyone being asked that entering Japan (as a tourist from normal-list countries).

#### (3) If, remarkably, the officer asks how long you will stay (perhaps just while chatting with you), obviously say "well 30 days but I'm hoping to stay longer".

To answer your specific question,

> Will staying longer [than my stamp] cause problems?

Your entry stamp will say 90 days. (As discussed above.)

**CORRECT, you absolutely can NOT stay longer than that stamp**. (ie, you can not stay longer than 90 days.)

If you do so, you will get in trouble. **Do not over stay the 90 days**.

Note that you also ask "Will staying longer ***'than planned'*** cause problems?"

That question is meaningless, nobody knows or cares about your plans. (I've never had a "plan" going to Japan - or anywhere! Heh! I just go, do what I want, and make sure I leave before the date in the stamp.)

You may be wondering what happens if you change your air ticket. The answer is nothing, nobody cares or knows. Just be absolutely sure to leave by the 90 day limit!  Enjoy!

Comment: hi, definitely NOT staying over 90 days because I don't want my future travels to be affected. Im just there to visit my gf and enjoy fall season.