ETA Japan Trip 2024
so I’m staying in Japan for a 1 month however if for some reason I extend my stay for up to 83 days, 7 days before my tourist visa expires. Would it be a good idea? I’m staying at my gf’s house and she wants to go Canada with me on that 84th day.
Is 7 days enough time to get out of Japan or is it risky?

What nationality are you? My understanding is it's quite difficult to extend Japanese tourist visas.

This question seems pretty similar to your earlier question [Will staying in Japan longer than planned cause problems]((https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/187611/will-staying-longer-than-planned-in-japan-cause-problems).

@Iambshaanxy I am Canadian

So you have a 90-day ETA, not 30 days? Please make this clearer in the question, although I'm also not seeing how this is any different from the one you previously asked.
